# I get an error in Android Studio saying Gradle project sync failed and it wants me to re-download independicies and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio

So I installed Android Studio and had some problems the second I made a project. It gave the error `Gradle project sync failed.`. So I tried again,tried to re-download the dependencies. I looked all over YouTube and Google,but I had not a bit of luck.!

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle.

Here follow these steps :

Go to gradle scripts and open gradle-wrapper.properties and than change the distributionUrl with this -

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

than Start the sync again.

Make sure you have a working internet during the process.

Answer (score 0):

try to used terminal, run gradlew tasks, wait for complete.